# python open folder on top of other windows

Tags: python

I have build in flask app, that recive a path and then open a folder.
my issue is that the folder is opened minimized and i would like to open it on top of all windows. how can I achieve it? I'm entering the URL http://localhost:9999/number from other web and it does open the folder just minimize :(

```
CLOSE_TAB = "<script>window.onload = window.close();</script>"
@app.route('/<number>')
def open_folder(number):
    try:
        home = str(Path.home())
        full_path = home + '/' + number
        folder_path = os.path.realpath(full_path)
        if os.path.exists(folder_path):
            #Open my folder by number
            os.startfile(folder_path)
            return CLOSE_TAB
        else:
            return FOLDER_NOT_FOUND
    except Exception as error:
        print(error)
        return "{}".format(str(error))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host="localhost", port=9999)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since Python 3.10 the function [`os.startfile`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.startfile) has parameter `show_cmd` which takes one of the int values documented for Win32's function [`ShowWindow`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-showwindow) for parameter `nCmdShow`.

Among others there is

- 1 for normal
- 2 for minimized
- 3 for maximized

It is up to the started application if the argument is respected.

Comment: not working, probably because the main function return a response to the web?
the folder is still opening minimized even if i use 3 or 1 in show_cmd parameter.